# On a webpage can I hijack the vertical scrolling action and make it horizontal?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, scroll

On a webpage can I hijack the vertical scrolling action and make it horizontal?

Please try and ignore the potential usability issues.

Comment: How do you plan to vertical scroll than? If the content is taller than the viewport what does horizontal scrolling help for?

Comment: "Please try and ignore the potential usability issues." Good thing you added this, I was about to give you a slap for even thinking about this ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a jQuery Plugin that does this, and you can specify it to only work when the mouse is over the target element:
http://flowplayer.org/tools/scrollable/index.html

Answer (score 2):

> On a webpage can I hijack the vertical scrolling action and make it horizontal?

Not as far as I know (except maybe by rotating the element - but that is probably not what you want).

You would have to re-arrange the contents to make the vertical scroll bar go away, and force a horizontal one instead.

Whether that is possible will strongly depend on the nature of the HTML elements inside the page.

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can do this.

Vertical scrolling is set to element.scrollTop

You could simply add a loop that catches scrollTop when it changes, sets it back to zero and then sets the scrollLeft to  be = to the changed position.

More so, an even better solution is to overwrite the onscroll event.

```
window.onscroll = function(event){

 event.preventDefault() // Stops the page from scrolling vertically.


 window.scrollLeft = event.scrollTop // This is not the correct event attribute, youll have to locate it yourself.
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could hook into the scroll event, check which plane is being scrolled, if it was the vertical then set the difference as the horizontal scroll and set the vertical scroll to it's previous value. Though I can imagine that would be incredibly expensive.